# how to implement 'pygame.sprite.spritecollideany' in conjunction with 'self.rect = temp_rect' to create collisions for the Enemy class?

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

The collisions for the Enemy class in my game are not functioning properly. How do I utilise `pygame.sprite.spritecollideany` with `self.rect = temp_rect` to create collisions for the Enemy class?

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, target, walls):
    super().__init__()
    self.image = pygame.Surface((TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))
    self.image.fill(RED)  # Enemy color is set to red
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))
    self.target = target  # The player character to follow
    self.walls = walls  # Reference to the walls group
  def update(self):
    # Calculate the direction vector from the enemy to the player character
    dx = self.target.rect.centerx - self.rect.centerx
    dy = self.target.rect.centery - self.rect.centery
    # Normalize the direction vector
    distance = math.hypot(dx, dy)
    if distance != 0:
      dx /= distance
      dy /= distance
      # Adjust speed for smoother movement
      speed = 1.7
      dx *= speed
      dy *= speed
      # Calculate the new position
      new_x = self.rect.x + dx
      new_y = self.rect.y + dy
      # Check for collisions with walls
      temp_rect = self.rect.move(dx, dy)
      if not pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, self.walls):
        self.rect = temp_rect
      else:
        # If there's a collision, try adjusting the direction
        # Randomize direction change to avoid getting stuck in corners
        if random.random() < 0.5:
          dx = random.choice([-1, 0, 1])
          dy = random.choice([-1, 0, 1])
        else:
          dx *= -1
          dy *= -1
          # Normalize the new direction vector
          distance = math.hypot(dx, dy)
          if distance != 0:
            dx /= distance
            dy /= distance
            # Adjust speed for smoother movement
            dx *= speed
            dy *= speed
            # Calculate the new position after collision
            temp_rect = self.rect.move(dx, dy)
            if not pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, self.walls):
              self.rect = temp_rect
```

The enemy moves and collides at first, but then it completely stops moving after the first collision. Please help me identify what went wrong and how to fix this.

Comment: Iam unfamiliar with pygame, but your sample code doesn't seem to include movement of enemy or characters.  How are these class instances being moved?  Look at your collision detection code and the aftermath of collision to find your problem  Edit question to focus on this aspect of your code.

Comment: @itprorh66 The code for the movement of the enemy is in the `update` method of the `Enemy class`. Code for the movement of the player character is in the `move` method of the `Character` class.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this part:

```
temp_rect = self.rect.move(dx, dy)
if not pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, self.walls):
   self.rect = temp_rect
```

In this part, you try to decide if the movement should be allowed or not. `temp_rect` contains the new position to the sprite, but when you call `pygame.sprite.spritecollideany`, you don't actually use the new position for collision detection, but the current position of the sprite. So the movement will be allowed, and the sprite moves into the wall.

You can move the sprite first, then do the collision detection, and if it hits a wall, undo the movement.

The same problem exists in this part:

```
# Calculate the new position after collision
temp_rect = self.rect.move(dx, dy)
if not pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, self.walls):
    self.rect = temp_rect
```

Here's a version with this behaviour corrected (it could still be improved, try using `pygame.Vector2` to make your life easier):

```
def update(self):
    # Calculate the direction vector from the enemy to the player character
    dx = self.target.rect.centerx - self.rect.centerx
    dy = self.target.rect.centery - self.rect.centery

    # Normalize the direction vector
    distance = math.hypot(dx, dy)
    if distance != 0:
        dx /= distance
        dy /= distance
        # Adjust speed for smoother movement
        speed = 1.7
        dx *= speed
        dy *= speed
        # Calculate the new position
        new_x = self.rect.x + dx
        new_y = self.rect.y + dy

        # Check for collisions with walls
        temp_rect = self.rect
        self.rect = self.rect.move(dx, dy)
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, self.walls):
            self.rect = temp_rect
            # If there's a collision, try adjusting the direction
            # Randomize direction change to avoid getting stuck in corners
            if random.random() < 0.5:
                dx = random.choice([-1, 0, 1])
                dy = random.choice([-1, 0, 1])
            else:
                dx *= -1
                dy *= -1
            # Normalize the new direction vector
            distance = math.hypot(dx, dy)
            if distance != 0:
                dx /= distance
                dy /= distance
                # Adjust speed for smoother movement
                dx *= speed
                dy *= speed

                # Calculate the new position after collision
                temp_rect = self.rect
                self.rect = self.rect.move(dx, dy)
                if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, self.walls):
                    self.rect = temp_rect
```

The next problem is that the evading that the sprites tries to do is random. If you use the corrected code, you'll see that the sprite will still get stuck on walls, but it starts to shake before eventually going around the wall. The sprite does not decide to go this or that way around a wall. It will move pretty much up/down/left/right randomly.

You could use some simple pathfinding (like A*) to find the best path to the player sprite.